# Parse all numbers in a paragraph and sum them in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, sum

I am doing the following JS exercise in which I need to parse all the numbers in the given paragraph and then sum all those numbers.

```js
function get_sum() {
    let s = document.getElementById('pc').textContent;
    let matches = s.match(/(\d+)/);
    let sum = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i < matches.length; ++i) {
        sum += matches[i];
    }
    console.log(sum);
}
```

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>PC</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <p id="pc"> The cost of the processor is 9000.
      The cost of the motherboard is 15000. The memory card is 6000.
      The price of the monitor is 7000. The hard disk price is 4000.
      Other item's cost is 6000. </p>

  <button type="button" onclick='get_sum()'>Get Sum</button>
  </body>
  </html>
```

## The output should be an evaluation of the expression of 9000+15000+6000+7000+4000+6000 i.e. 47000

Answer (score 3):

Here:

```
    function get_sum() {
        let s = document.getElementById('pc').textContent;
        let matches = s.match(/(\d+)/g);
        let sum = 0;
        for(let i = 0; i < matches.length; ++i) {
            sum += Number(matches[i]);
        }
        console.log(sum);
    }
```

added `g` for global,
added `Number()` because you get strings...

Comment: @iAmOren Why global? What is the need for that?

Comment: @Sherlock, for all occurrences, not just the first.

Comment: I hope this is working for you - if so, please select and up-vote my answer!

Answer (score 3):

```js
const pc = document.querySelector("#pc");
const totalBtn = document.querySelector("#btn-total");

totalBtn.addEventListener("click", e => {
  const prices = pc.innerText.match(/\d+/g);

  const total = prices.reduce(
    (total, price) => (+price) + total, 0
  );

  console.log(total);
});
```

```html
<p id="pc"> The cost of the processor is 9000. The cost of the motherboard is 15000. The memory card is 6000. The price of the monitor is 7000. The hard disk price is 4000. Other item's cost is 6000. </p>
<button id="btn-total">Calculate Total</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a small change in the regular expression.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>PC</title>
</head>
<body>
<p id="pc"> The cost of the processor is 9000.
    The cost of the motherboard is 15000. The memory card is 6000.
    The price of the monitor is 7000. The hard disk price is 4000.
    Other item's cost is 6000. </p>

<button type="button" onclick='get_sum()'>Get Sum</button>
</body>
</html>
```

```
<script>
    function get_sum() {
        let s = document.getElementById('pc').textContent;
        let matches = s.match(/\d+/g);
        let sum = 0;
        for(let i = 0; i < matches.length; ++i) {
            sum += parseInt(matches[i]);
        }
        console.log(sum);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Atleast have decency to credit them when you copy their work.

Comment: Are you serious? Please check the time I posted and the same claim I can make also.